# Shiny application can't download lattice plot

Tags: r, image, shiny, download, lattice

First of all i'm beginner at Shiny. I'm trying to save locally the plot (using button) i made in my application with `lattice` package. However, I am unable to create a corresponding function in the server.

Please help

download button and plot in my UI:

```
downloadButton('downloadPlot2', 'Save lattice plot locally')
.
.
.
tabPanel(names(panel_choices)[2], value = panel_choices[[2]], plotOutput("plot2"))
```

Server:

```
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    print(plotInput2())
  })
  
  plotInput2 <- reactive({
    md <- mydata()
    md.long <- melt(md, id = "ID", measure = colnames(md)[-1])
    xyplot(value~md.long[,1],data = md.long,main="visualization of data from csv file",ylim = c(input$value[1],input$value[2]),
           xlab = "ID",ylab = "values of variables")
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `downloadHandler`, just paste this inside your server:

```
output$downloadPlot2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = '',
    content = function(file) {
      png(file)
      print(plotInput2())
      dev.off()
    })
```